# Why System Monitor doesn't show all processes, though I selected "All"?

Tags: cpu-load

I selected "All processes". I see that it eats 2%-4% CPU:

[image]

However, in "Resources" all cores are loaded way higher:

[image]

"All processes" are selected:

[image]

And I run it as `sudo`

Any ideas? How to see all this hidden CPU activity? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI is confusing because in the first picture the CPU usage is for all cores; while the second picture shows the CPU usage for each core.

Thus if you've got 8 CPUs and it shows you're using 1%; it's actually worth up to 8% of a single core. Since you have two processes consuming 1% each, that means a single core may be consuming 16% and alternating between CPUs (which is quite common)

The other processes may be consuming more than 0%, but gets rounded to 0% (eg. 0.49% -> 0% even though 0.49% actually means up to 3.92% of a single core). The same happens with the two processes consuming 1%: They may be consuming up to 1.49% which would account for 11.92% each. That's up to 23.84% of a single CPU!

All of this is consistent with what you're showing.

Admittedly process explorer should update its UI to account for the high core of today's computers. I get this problem very often when a process is "consuming 4%" but that's actually 100% of a single CPU when you've got 24 threads...

Also the kernel consumes a bit of CPU and will appear in the graphs but not in the process tab.